# Need guidance on upgrading Ruby on Rails application from version 5.1.2 to newer version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have inherited a Ruby on Rails project that was developed on version 5.1.2 of Rails and version 2.5.2 of Ruby. I am now looking to upgrade the application to a newer version, but I don't have much experience with upgrading Rails applications.

Could you please guide me on how to upgrade the application version?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: This is a Q&A site for practical programming questions that can be authoritively answered - the scope here is way to wide for this to be answered in a few paragraphs and "Could you please guide me?"  isn't an actual answerable question. You're going to have to do the legwork and reseach the topic and lay out a strategy for upgrading. There are guides for upgrading each rails version as well as books about how to work with legacy code without losing your sanity (or job).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to follow the guide listed here:  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

The main thing that we had trouble with, and I dont know if this will apply to you, was going from Paperclip to Activestorage.  (Non-trivial application).  However, you could punt on that and use one of the forked Paperclip repos for a little while longer.